# How to print the value of getter method

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I created the below example in eclipse. I am following a tutorial, and it mentioned that I can use `print(s1.captain)` to print the captain name for example. The tutorial wants to show that `kotlin` automatically generate the `setters` and `getters`.

In my code the print statement does not print any thing

**Main**:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var s1 = Stronghold1("JJ",7)
    print(s1.captain)
}
```

**stronghold**:

```
abstract class Stronghold(name: String, location: String)
```

**stronghold1**

```
class Stronghold1(captain: String, capacity: Int) : Stronghold("GerMachine", "Bonn")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, constructor arguments are only turned into properties if they are marked as `val` or `var`. In your case, `captain`, `capacity`, `name`, and `location` are just arguments to the constructor. They aren't made into properties.

To get `captain` and `capacity` as properties, add `val` to them:

```
class Stronghold1(val captain: String, val capacity: Int) : Stronghold("GerMachine", "Bonn")
//                ^^^                  ^^^
//                add                  add
```

You probably want to do the same thing with `Stronghold` as well:

```
abstract class Stronghold(val name: String, val location: String)
//                        ^^^               ^^^
//                        add               add
```

Comment: you may also want to turn them into data classes to get a default `toString` implementation